# Converting Request from CURL to PHP's Guzzle to access WHMCS API

Tags: php, api, curl, guzzle, psr-7

I'm attempting to learn the latest version of Guzzle (6.2) and convert my cURL requests to the WHMCS API.

Using the example code from: http://docs.whmcs.com/API:JSON_Sample_Code

```
// The fully qualified URL to your WHMCS installation root directory
$whmcsUrl = "https://www.yourdomain.com/billing/";

// Admin username and password
$username = "Admin";
$password = "password123";

// Set post values
$postfields = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => md5($password),
    'action' => 'GetClients',
    'responsetype' => 'json',
);

// Call the API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whmcsUrl . 'includes/api.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

// Attempt to decode response as json
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);

// Dump array structure for inspection
var_dump($jsonData);
```

I haven't as yet been able to work out how to get the same thing to work with Guzzle.

Here's what I have tried:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

// The fully qualified URL to your WHMCS installation root directory
$whmcsUrl = "https://www.yourdomain.com/billing/";

// Admin username and password
$username = "Admin";
$password = "password123";

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $whmcsUrl,
    'timeout'  => 30,
    'auth' => [$username, md5($password)],
    'action' => 'GetClients',
    'responsetype'  =>  'json'
]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'includes/api.php');
echo $response->getStatusCode();
print_r($response,true);
```

This will most likely be a very obvious answer to those who've used Guzzle before.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use 'form_params' to send urlencoded POST data:

```
$username = "Admin";
$password = "password123";

// Set post values
$postfields = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => md5($password),
    'action' => 'GetClients',
    'responsetype' => 'json',
);

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.yourdomain.com',
    'timeout'  => 30,
]);

$response = $client->request('POST', '/billing/includes/api.php', [
    'form_params' => $postfields
]);
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks very much!